# POST and PATCH for a nested resource in REST API

Tags: rest, api, api-design, http

One post can have many comments.

How can I design REST API urls for HTTP POST and HTTP PATCH for comments.
My idea is to have the following endpoints:

```
HTTP GET: /posts/{postId}/comments
HTTP GET (all comments): /comments
HTTP POST: /posts/{postId}/comments
HTTP PATCH: /comments/{commentId}
```

Are these urls correct? Because I thought also about:

```
HTTP PATCH: /posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}
```

But here a user needs to know also {postId} to edit a comment so:

```
HTTP PATCH: /comments/{commentId}
```

looks better, I think. What do you think?

Comment: how exactly do you see a partial update of a comment to work?

Answer (score 3):

[REST](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

HTTP expects that, to patch a resource, the PATCH request will target the same resource identifier as a GET request.  (This is a consequence of how caching works, see [RFC 9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-constructing-responses-from).)

So if you are fetching the current representation of a "comments resource" via

```
GET /comments/1
```

The you (RFC 2119) SHOULD be sending patches to the representation of that resource via

```
PATCH /comments/1
```

so that general purpose caches can understand the semantics of what is going on, and do intelligent things.

---

An important idea in REST is the [uniform interface constraint](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5); among other things, it implies that everyone should understand the semantics of requests and responses the same way -- no one resource should be a "special case" that assumes different meaning to the messages.

It follows that "nested resources" should understand request messages the same way that everything else does; GET means GET, PATCH means PATCH, and so on.

---

As for the design of your resource identifiers, the machines *don't care* (that's part of the point of "uniform" interface), so choose spelling conventions that best meet the needs of the human beings you value.

Comment: OK, thank you, so I will do:
HTTP GET (get post comments): /posts/{postId}/comments || 
HTTP GET (get all comments): /comments || 
HTTP GET (get single comment): /comments/{commentId} || 
HTTP POST: /posts/{postId}/comments || 
HTTP PATCH: /comments/{commentId}